# How to schedule a local repeated notification that starts at a certain date?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

How do I add a repeated notification that’s starts at a certain time?

Regarding to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1) 
 a notification trigger is either scheduled for an absolute calendar date/time using [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger) or repeated using a [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger).

Is there a way schedule a mix of both types?

Comment: Do you want the notification to trigger at a certain *date* or a certain *time*?  If *time*, the simply set the trigger time date components and specify repeats=true.  This will then trigger the next time the specified *time* is reached and then every day after that at the same time

Comment: I'd like the very first notification be presented at a specific date+time not an interval. After that initial notification all following notifications should be repeated at a certain time interval.

Comment: Then I don’t believe you can do it with the new notification framework. You can use the older, deprecated framework.

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm having the same requirement. Would it mean to trigger 2 separate schedules? One for the first fixed date and then a repeating one? But wait, this would actually lead to the same logical issue..